# Youtube API not returning updated results

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am developing a simple video app which will trigger an Intent to fetch any new videos update from a specific channel, using **Youtube Api V3**.

```
search.setKey(Constant.DEVELOPER_KEY);
search.setChannelId(channelID);
search.setOrder("date");
search.setPublishedAfter(new DateTime(yesterday));
search.setType("video");
search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/publishedAt)");
search.setMaxResults((long) 50);
SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();

List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
```

**Problem:** It returns me a list of not updated results.

Example in URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=date&type=video&channelId=UC52X5wxOL_s5yw0dQk7NtgA&key=your_api_key&maxResults=50

**Problem Description:**

1. For a couple of days monitoring this behavior, I found out that, firstly, there's always some other video that I could find in this channel by going to Youtube website itself. And the video just needs like another 30 or 60 minutes to be in my searching results.
2. Well the delay is actually fine for me, what I do not understand is, sometime, say there is video 1, video 2, and video 3, where 1 is uploaded before 2, and 2 is uploaded before 3.So in the above case I would expect for a result of (in the URL I specified to order by date desc) 3-2-1, or 2-1, or only 1. But what I get is strangely, 3-1. 2 will comes in later at maybe another half an hour. I mean, if the delay is an issue, at least it should appear in the list with a proper ordering?

**Expected Solution:** To have a searching result that will be ordered by date accurately, so that whenever I try to requery the videos, I just have to get what is published after my last video retrieved. Not the way as in my example getting everything since yesterday.

Thank you for your time, I really am looking towards a solution.

Comment: For anyone that needs a screenshot on what happened, kindly refer to comment section on Ahmed's answer.

Answer (score 0):

So firstly V3 of the API is currently experimental and I wouldn't recommend using it til it's been signed off and what not.

Secondly, I'm never a fan of client libraries and prefer to make API calls directly, that way you can make sure the call is being made in the way that you want. So, for example, here's a simple call to retrieve the videos off my channel in the order of which they were published: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?orderby=published&author=ahmednuaman

I'd recommend using this method for now and having a look at the interactive API demo (http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html) to brew up your call and to confirm that the tests are returning the data you desire.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but on first attempt of trying this API, I still get incorrect result. This is what I see from YouTube http://i.imgur.com/KAfxP3l.png, and here is what I have from the API http://i.imgur.com/dHG5gEP.png. As you can see, my first result is actually pointing to second video on the channel. This is the API call I did http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?orderby=published&author=AssociatedPress

Comment: Ah it could be a case of restrictions regarding the distribution of the video: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html?m=1

Comment: Not really, as you can see what I had monitored, also I did mention that I used direct API call if you did not notice. Those video will eventually be included into result list, just later. Same goes to your example API call, the video excluded earlier, is now included